# orderByChild query not working on addListenerForSingleValueEvent Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to order my database by child value "Month" but orderByChild is not working. It works when I use onChildEventListener instead of addListenerForSingleValueEvent But I dont wnat to use childEventListener

Here is my database

```
"Stats" : {
    "2019" : {
      "YxdZZHGy3rW4xdjORfk2i5mFRYG2" : {
        "August" : {
          "Weight" : {
            "Body_Fat" : "29",
            "Month" : 8,
            "Weight" : "68"
          }
        },
        "October" : {
          "Weight" : {
            "Body_Fat" : "29",
            "Month" : 10,
            "Weight" : "67"
          }
        },
        "September" : {
          "Weight" : {
            "Body_Fat" : "28.5",
            "Month" : 9,
            "Weight" : "65.5"
          }
        }
      }
    }
},
```

And here is the java code

```
 userStatsDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Query query = userStatsDatabase.child(ds.getKey()).child("Weight").orderByChild("Month").limitToFirst(12);
                    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                pastMonthsBodyFat = Float.parseFloat(map.get("Body_Fat").toString());
                                pastMonthsWeight = Float.parseFloat(map.get("Weight").toString());

                                pastWeightList.add(pastMonthsWeight);
                                pastBodyFatList.add(pastMonthsBodyFat);
                                Toast.makeText(Stats.this, map.get("Month").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
```

The Toast should print month values in order 8,9,10 but it is printing the values 8,10,9

Comment: What node does `userStatsDatabase` point to?

Comment: The above code will be quite problematic with nested foreach loop. I suggest to use recyclerview to retrieve the first list. By click certain node from recyclerview retrieve the key of that node and try to query it.

Comment: How is `userStatsDatabase` initialized?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it points to User/Stats/2019/UserID then I use a For loop to get each month

Comment: I gave up using Firebase queries to sort the data , Im sure there is nothing wrong with my code,anyways I decided to sort the data "after" adding the data to the arrayList using Collections.sort and it worked. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `userStatsDatabase` points to this JSON (for a specific user):

```
  {
    "August" : {
      "Weight" : {
        "Body_Fat" : "29",
        "Month" : 8,
        "Weight" : "68"
      }
    },
    "October" : {
      "Weight" : {
        "Body_Fat" : "29",
        "Month" : 10,
        "Weight" : "67"
      }
    },
    "September" : {
      "Weight" : {
        "Body_Fat" : "28.5",
        "Month" : 9,
        "Weight" : "65.5"
      }
    }
  }
```

Then you can get the results in order of `Month` with:

```
Query query = userStatsDatabase..orderByChild("Weight/Month");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot monthSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      System.out.println(monthSnapshot.getKey()); // August, September, October
      System.out.println(monthSnapshot.child("Weight/Month").getValue(Long.class)); // 8, 9, 10
    }
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave up using Firebase queries to sort the data , Im sure there is nothing wrong with my code,anyways I decided to sort it "after" adding the data to the arrayList using Collections.sort and it worked. Thanks

P.S if someone knows why my firebase query didnt work I would still like to know the reason :S

Here is the code in case someone else needs to sort data from an arrayList

```
//sort the item  to show months in ascending order
Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<PastMonthsWeightStats>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(PastMonthsWeightStats obj1, PastMonthsWeightStats obj2) {
        // ## Ascending order
        // return obj1.firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(obj2.firstName); // To compare string values
        //return Float.valueOf(obj1.getMonthNumber()).compareTo(Float.valueOf(obj2.getMonthNumber())); // To compare integer values

        // ## Descending order
        // return obj2.firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(obj1.firstName); // To compare string values
        return Integer.valueOf(obj2.getMonthNumber()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(obj1.getMonthNumber())); // To compare integer values
    }
});
```